# C#　64bit DB接続 paradoxについて

Tags: c#, database

```
// OLE DBから原簿データを取得する
conn.ConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Paradox 5.x;", inputFolderName);
conn.Open();
```

この操作は、この種類の IISAM ではサポートされていません。この操作を実行するには、2007 Microsoft Office system 以前のバージョンを使用してください。
というエラーがでました。
なにとぞ、ご教授よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージの通りです。[Access 2010 で廃止、変更される機能](https://support.office.com/ja-jp/article/Access-2010-%E3%81%A7%E5%BB%83%E6%AD%A2%E3%80%81%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E6%A9%9F%E8%83%BD-9714e5e4-4bbc-490f-97b6-29a7730381cb?ui=ja-JP&rs=ja-JP&ad=JP)に

> Paradox 3、4、5、6、7 のデータのエクスポート、インポート、およびリンクの設定は実行できなくなりました。

の記載があります。
なお、pgrhoさんの挙げられている`Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0`は32bit専用ですので64bitアプリケーションでは使用できません。

Answer (score 0):

プロバイダー名を`Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0`にするのはどうでしょうか。

Comment: Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0を使わないで接続したいです。無理なのでしょうか？

Comment: @BAKZ 無理です。アプリケーション全体、もしくは関連機能のみを分離して32ビットアプリケーションとして動作させ、Jet 4.0を使用すべきですね。

Comment: @pgrhoさん、そうですよね。なにかあればと思ったのですが、ありがとうございます。